# issue with ios woosim bluetooth printing version iOS[2012.11.01]

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, bluetooth

I am using woosim printer for bluetooth version. I use it to print the different bills. I am using version iOS[2012.11.01]. In the previous version I was facing the issue that some portion was not printed, when I am using the new version, even if I give command to print 5 bills, it just stops printing after printing some portion of 3rd bill every time. I checked paper and everything was ok. I am currently using xcode 4.2. Please help.